# Pydoc messes up with -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Tags: python, emacs, encoding, pydoc

I edit Python scripts with Emacs, and I always put this at the beginning of my scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

It is recommended (at least, not discourage) in [PEP 0236](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

However, I just found that `pydoc` doesn't recognize (ignore) it correctly:

```
$ pydoc myscript.py
Help on module myscript:

NAME
    myscript - # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Is there a way to fix that? Or a good alternative to using `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-`?

I'm using Python 2.6

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Have you checked it at pydoc?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I'm relatively new to Python. How do I check that?

Answer (score 7):

It appears that if you actually provide a documentation string the encoding line will be skipped.

File contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Documentation for myscript"""
```

pydoc output:

```
$ pydoc myscript.py
Help on module myscript:

NAME
    myscript - Documentation for myscript
```